# How to Post Image to API as base64 url alongside with another data such as String etc?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new on Flutter.
I don't know how to do a post method in which the body of the request contains multi-type data like String and Image ( I want to post Image as Base64 Url ). What Should I do?

Currently, this is my code

```
void submit() async {
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse('https://yourendpoint.com'),
          body: {
            'kategori': selectedValue.toString().toLowerCase(),
            'tanggal': dateinput.text,
            'deskripsi': fileinput.text,
            'file': ''
          },
          headers: {
            'access-token': 'access-token'
          });

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Keluhan anda akan segera kami tangani');
        Navigator.pop(context);
      } else {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Format yang anda masukkan salah');
        print(response.statusCode);
        print(response.body);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

I try to post it as String and it just doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If you have any questions, feel free to ask :)

```
body: {
  'kategori': selectedValue.toString().toLowerCase(),
  'tanggal': dateinput.text,
  'deskripsi': fileinput.text,
  'file': _image != null ? 'data:image/png;base64' + base64Encode(_image.readAsBytesSync()) : ''
},
```

Comment: 'data/image/png;base64' is the path of the image isn't it?

Comment: @FikryAhmadHaykhal I made a typo. it's `data:image/png;base64` not `data/image/png;base64`.

It's not the path of the image. Path of the image is `_image`